# Why are properties in Swift non-atomic by default?

Tags: ios, swift, thread-safety, atomic

As in Objecive-C, properties are atomic by default. This guarantees that a valid value will be returned. Non-atomic properties have no guarantee regarding the returned value then, why in Swift properties are non-atomic? And how can we change this behavior in Swift?

Comment: Because they're expensive.

Comment: You mean atomic properties are expensive. But that would lead to thread-unsafe code. As I said, there will be no guarantee regarding the returned value.

Comment: No, that *can* lead to thread unsafe code. Paying the price for thread safety is now opt-in. If you want atomic properties, you can implement them yourself.

Comment: Atomic accessors are generally insufficient to achieve thread safety. And when you implement higher level synchronization, the atomic accessors become redundant and add unnecessary layer of inefficiency. As the [Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) reminds us, “Although locks and other synchronization tools are useful, they do impact the performance of any application.”

Comment: Apple’s counsel (from same doc): “The best way to implement concurrency is to reduce the interactions and inter-dependencies between your concurrent tasks.”